# I ran the exact same code twice and got different outputs

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

I'm working on a simulation in R to model some human behavior and for some reason, my simulation is alternating between two different result patterns. Below is the code for the two simulations that I'm running. 10000 iterations should be sufficient to converge on a single pattern, and yet, that is not what is happening. I'm banging my head against a wall trying to figure out what is happening--I would love any and all assistance!

EDIT:
It was suggested that I add some additional details about what I'm trying to simulate, here are those details!

I'm modeling a so-called "balloon-popping paradigm" where one is tasked with estimating a value (variable name i2 and is3 here) and getting as close as possible to a true value (randNum2 and randNum3) without going over or under that value. I'm trying to model how this process works when there is variability in the true value. This variability is coming from multiple sources which is why I have multiple runif functions being added together.

The expected converging pattern is that when there is more variability in the true value, the simulation should result in a more conservative estimate. Sometimes when I run this, I get that pattern, othertimes, I get a pattern where regardless of the amount of variability, the simulation converges on the same value.

```
OsimulationShort <- data.frame(timeEstimate = double(), averagePayout = double())
for (i2 in seq(from = 1, to = 25, by = .5)){
  temp2 <- data.frame(timeEstimate = double(), payout = double())
  for (n2 in 1:10000){
      randNum2 <- runif(n=1,min=3,max=7) + runif(n=1,min=-1,max=1)#+ rnorm(n=1,m = 0, sd = 1) 
      if (i2 > randNum2){
         reward2 = 0
      } else{
         reward2 = i2
      }
  temp2 <- rbind(temp2,data.frame(timeEstimate = i2, payout = reward2))    
  }  
  OsimulationShort <- rbind(OsimulationShort,data.frame(timeEstimate = i2, averagePayout = mean(temp2$payout)))
}

optimal <- rbind(optimal, data.frame(timeLongOrShort = "Short", distType = "Variability", riskCondition = "NO OVER", opTime = OsimulationShort$timeEstimate[OsimulationShort$averagePayout == max(OsimulationShort$averagePayout)]))


UsimulationLong <- data.frame(timeEstimate = double(), averagePayout = double())
for (i3 in seq(from = 1, to = 25, by = .5)){
  temp3 <- data.frame(timeEstimate = double(), payout = double())
  for (n3 in 1:10000){
      randNum3 <- runif(n=1,min=9,max=21) + runif(n=1,min=-3,max=3)#+ rnorm(n=1,m = 0, sd =3) 
      if (i3 < randNum3){
         reward3 = 0
      } else{
         reward3 = (2*randNum3) -i3
      }
  temp3 <- rbind(temp3,data.frame(timeEstimate = i3, payout = reward3))    
  }  
  UsimulationLong <- rbind(UsimulationLong,data.frame(timeEstimate = i3, averagePayout = mean(temp3$payout)))
}

optimal <- rbind(optimal, data.frame(timeLongOrShort = "Long", distType = "Variability", riskCondition = "NO UNDER", opTime = UsimulationLong$timeEstimate[UsimulationLong$averagePayout == max(UsimulationLong$averagePayout)]))
```

I ran the exact same code twice in a row, and got vastly different results.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you use random number generating functions or random sampling functions like `runif()` for simulations etc., using `set.seed(000)` or any other arbitrary seed number allows you to reproduce the same output

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't 10000 iterations cause converging results? I was getting outputs from this that varied quite a lot, a difference of ~2-3.

Comment: ahhh I see your issue is more about the convergence. then you might wanna add a little context to the algorithm like what are you sampling, what value is supposed to converge and how is that value computed. this way we can see what might cause the variability or the results not converging

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I added those details! :)

Answer (score 0):

You say you get very different results when you run the code different times.
But have you computed the variability expected on the results?

I ran each of the simulations (short and long) twice on just 100 iterations (i.e. both `n2` and `n3` in your code go from 1 to 100) and I get what I believe are similar results. I think the observed variability is the expected one.

Below are the plots of `averagePayout` generated against the index of the data frame  (respectively `USimulationShort` and `USimulationLong`) and we see a similar pattern in each output.

[image: ShortSimulation]

[image: LongSimulation]